# Set a variable to today's date (vb script / aspx)

Tags: asp.net, variables, vbscript

I'm trying to set a variable to today's date using VB within an ASPX file. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: Simply use DateTime.now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as you wish to declare and assign the variable, you can use it further in your code

```
<% Dim a As String = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, thats great

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

This will declare your `date` variable:-

```
<% Dim date As String = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
```

This will print the value of variable date on response:-

```
<%= date %>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i assign that when i delcare the dim though? e.g. dim today = date

Comment: well, its vbscript within an asp.net document. THanks for your answer.

Comment: @SamFarr - Check my edit and I hope you need it on markup page. If you need it only in VBScript then I misunderstood your question, please let me know so that I can delete it.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks again Rahul :).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Date()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y5tew48%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [Now()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w568awd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> WScript.Echo Date()
>> WScript.Echo Now()
>>
23.04.2015
23.04.2015 12:15:46  ' <-- german locale
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i assign that when i delcare the dim though? e.g. dim today = date

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime.Today property:

```
<%= DateTime.Today %>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Thanks. How would i assign that when i delcare the dim though? e.g. dim today = date

Comment: Like it is shown in the link: Dim thisDay As DateTime = DateTime.Today